# Kubernetes Change-Cause

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I don't know why the change cause below is always kubectl create although I run different kubectl commands. The second revision should be 'kubectl apply' not 'kubectl create' and the third should be 'kubectl set image'.

I am running Kubernetes v1.18.5

```bash
[garfield@kubemaster1 Kube]$ kubectl rollout history deployment/myapp-deployment
deployment.apps/myapp-deployment 
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
1         kubectl create --filename=deployment-definition.yml --record=true
2         kubectl create --filename=deployment-definition.yml --record=true

[garfield@kubemaster1 Kube]$ kubectl set image deployment.apps/myapp-deployment nginx-container=nginx:1.12-perl
deployment.apps/myapp-deployment image updated
[garfield@kubemaster1 Kube]$ kubectl rollout history deployment/myapp-deployment
deployment.apps/myapp-deployment 
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
1         kubectl create --filename=deployment-definition.yml --record=true
2         kubectl create --filename=deployment-definition.yml --record=true
3         kubectl create --filename=deployment-definition.yml --record=true
```

UPDATE:
I should have added `--record` at the end of every `kubectl` command

Comment: `--record` flag is deprecated check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73814500/record-has-been-deprecated-then-what-is-the-alternative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I should have added --record at the end of every kubectl.

Adding [more details](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#create):

> `--record`: Record current kubectl command in the resource
> annotation. If set to false, do not record the command. If set to
> true, record the command. If not set, default to updating the existing
> annotation value only if one already exists.

Answer (score 0):

The kubectl set image or apply command doesn't record the changes by default in order to record it we need to set --record = true or just --record

But the point to be noted is the --record is depicted since 2018 and K8s official documentation still teaches --record You can use it until K8s provides an alternative

Answer (score -1):

I hava a  same problem with  you.

```
# kubectl set image deployment/nginx-deployment nginx-deployment=nginx:1.9.1

deployment.apps/nginx-deployment image updated
```

```
# kubectl rollout history deployment/nginx-deployment
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment 
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
1         kubectl apply --filename=nginx-deployment.yaml --record=true
2         kubectl apply --filename=nginx-deployment.yaml --record=true
```