# --record has been deprecated, then what is the alternative

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

When I am running the below command to record the change cause -

```
kubectl set image deployment.v1.apps/deploy1 nginx=nginx:1.16.0 --record
```

Then it records the change cause but shows that `--record` has been deprecated.

```
Flag --record has been deprecated, `--record` will be removed in the future
deployment.apps/deploy1 image updated
```

And when I run the command `kubectl set image deployment.v1.apps/deploy1 nginx=nginx:1.16.0` without `--record` then it does not record the change cause.

So my question is if the `--record` has been deprecated and with be removed in the future then what is the easy alternative of that to record change? ( I mean to record the command using which I have done rollout ).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not sure if it's deprecated or will be fully.

You can use the **[annotate](https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_annotate/)** to manage the history same way.

1. **Create the deployment**

   kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx:1.16.0 --replicas 1
2. **check the history**

   kubectl rollout history deployment nginx
3. **update the image on deployment**

   kubectl set image deployment nginx nginx=nginx:latest
4. **Annotate the deployment now and create the history**

   kubectl annotate deployment nginx kubernetes.io/change-cause="version change to 1.16.0 to latest" --overwrite=true
5. ****Check the history****

   kubectl rollout history deployment nginx

Answer (score 5):

The best way to keep a clean documented history of your rollouts is using:

```
kubectl annotate --help
```

You can use for example:

```
kubectl annotate deployment/nginx-deployment kubernetes.io/change-cause="image updated to 1.16.1"
```

CHANGE-CAUSE is copied from the Deployment annotation kubernetes.io/change-cause to its revisions upon creation.
Then you would get a message like this when revisiting the history.

[image]

You can also find the information in the documentation under Workloads -> Resources -> Resources -> Checking Rollout History of a Deployment.

[Kubernetes Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#checking-rollout-history-of-a-deployment)